# Force span with icon to wrap with preceding span

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

Working with Angular and Bootstrap icons.  My labels are spans that are dynamically populated by a ng-bind-html.  For validation, I am appending an additional span with an icon.  When the width of the 2 spans exceeds the browser window the icon is wrapped to the next line.  I want the icon to only wrap with content from the first span.  Here is a fiddle.

```
<label>
<span>Dynamically bound text loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong</span>
&nbsp;
<span>
    <i style="font-size: 10px" class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></i>    
</span>
```

[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/fk6anozs/)

Comment: I think you need to add a bit more detail, maybe with a picture showing your expected result; as it stands now, this looks like the standard way that bootstrap wraps items; it breaks each word at certain intervals, not just the two spans.

Comment: I can't have the icon on a line by itself.  If the content must wrap, I need at least one word from the first span to wrap with the icon.

Comment: it wouldn't break that way even if the content was all in the same span, so again, I don't really think this has anything to do with the way the content is generated; you'll have to write custom css to control the wrap.

Comment: Of course it's css.  That is what I'm asking for.

Comment: You didn't word the question that way; you listed the angularjs tag, and specifically mention `ng-bind-html`, which will lead many to think that you are trying to suggest that angular is to blame for the layout issues.

Comment: Many?  See the keyword tags.

Comment: my point is, the angular tags and the mention of `ng-bind-html` don't bring any value to the question regarding your layout, and asking a CSS question without showing any CSS used is only likely to get the question ignored.  I would like to see your question have a favorable answer, I'm just trying to help you to frame the question correctly so that can happen.

Comment: A solution I located previously used the text within the first span to force the icon to attach to the last word, which won't work with a dynamic bind.  You have nothing informative to offer here.

Comment: again, really no need to get defensive, I'm very much trying to help you.  Now, you are suggesting that you tried something that didn't work with dynamic binding, which definitely makes it an angular issue.  However, you didn't mention this in the question, or show the solution that doesn't work, so it can be tested and adapted.

Comment: can you update the question to include the solution that works in some situations but not in this one?

Answer (score 0):

After consideration I omitted the spans and instead of binding html I used trustAsHtml() to display the label.  Browsers will not move the icon down without the preceding text so long as they are not lead with a white space.

This must be added to the controller

```
$scope.trustAsHtml = function (string) {
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(string);
};
```

and this is the html

```
{{(trustAsHtml(Dynamic.text))}}&nbsp;
<i style="display: inline" 
    class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk glyphicon-required">
</i>
```